# how to change action (route) before it reaches the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

anybody knows how to change the route/ the action (just the action, no need to change the controller) in the Application_BeginRequest method, or anyware else before it reaches the controller

this is my current solution:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType == "application/x-amf")
        {
            //... some stuff
            filterContext.ActionParameters["target"] = body.Target;
            //...
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the target in a catchem all action

```
 [MyFilter]
 public ActionResult(string target)
 {
      return RedirectToAction(target);
 }
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this, and it I have a feeling it may not even be what you're looking for.  Can you expand on the question?  Maybe give some examples of the result you're looking to achieve?

Comment: @ThinkingSites basically I check for some Request Parameters (Content-Type) and if it matches the condition then I get the action name from the data sent, so I need to redirect to that action

Comment: I've edited my question, probably it will make more sense now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two methods come to mind CreateActionInvoker and HandleUnknownAction can both do what you're looking for depending on how and why you're doing it.

```
public class MyController
{
        protected override IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker()
        {
            return base.CreateActionInvoker();
        }
        protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
        {
            base.HandleUnknownAction(actionName);
        }
}
```

**EDIT** adding example of action invoker

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected override IActionInvoker CreateActionInvoker()
    {
        if (this.Request.ContentType == "application/x-amf")
        {
            return new XAMFActionInvoker();
        }
        return base.CreateActionInvoker();
    }

    public class XAMFActionInvoker : IActionInvoker
    {
        public bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
        {
            // find the action you want to invoke
            var method = controllerContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethod("xamfAction");
            var result = (ActionResult)method.Invoke(controllerContext.Controller,... your actionName parameters...);
            result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Another option, if you're looking to override more than actions, but controllers as well is changing the default ControllerFactory.  In your Application_Start set a new controller factory to a custom on that you built for this occasion.  This is fairly complex however so I don't recommend it unless you need a lot of control.

```
 ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(IController factory)
```

**EDIT 3**
The last example would be to not add any actions and just override HandleUnknownAction. This will allow you to custom route your action to whichever method you like.

Comment: I don't quite understand how can this help

Comment: I'll edit my code around the IActionInvoker to make use of what you're put up already.

Comment: I did `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Regex.Replace(Request.RawUrl, @"[/,\\]\w+\z", "/" + target))` in Application_BeginRequest, but your solutions also look valid, might use them in the future